# program to know all the huiwen number doesn't work well

Tags: c

this program is build to know all the huiwen number from 1 to 256

**like 11^2=121  so 11 is a huiwen.**

actually I have a good one
but I am confuse about why this program doesn't work well.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int is_huiwen(int l)
{
     //DON'T WORK?WHY?
    int number[20]={0};
    int i,j,k;
    int f=l*l;

    for(j=0;f;j++)
    {
        number[j]=f%10;
        f/=10;
    }

    for(k=0;j-k>0;k++,j--)
    {
        if(number[j]!=number[k] )
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;


    /* this is ok
    int y=0;
    int t = l*l;
    int x = t;
    do
    {
        y=y*10+t%10;
        t /= 10;    
    }
    while(t);

    if(x==y)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
    */
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int flag;
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {      
        flag=is_huiwen(i);
        if(flag)
        {
        printf("%d is huiwen",i);   
        }
        else
        {
        printf("\n");   
        }
    }
    printf("end\n\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

end.

Comment: `if(number[j]!=number[k] )` --> `if(number[j-1]!=number[k] )`

Comment: What is huiwen number?

Comment: Are you asking why `int number[20]={0};` doesn't work? It might be due to using an old compiler that doesn't understand C99 or C11.

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Thank you all and sorry for not notice it.I will look carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the `if( number[j] != number[k] )`line as pointed out by BluePixy.

The correction is `if( number[j-1] != number[k] )`

I would to point out that the code has hidden the problem partly because of a smattering of one letter variable names and inconsistent naming.

Here is the code that I used to find the same solution

```
int is_huiwen_2(int L )
{
    int ret = 1;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int t = L * L;
    int number[8] = { 0 };

    for( j = 0; t; j++)
    {
        number[j] = t % 10;
        t /= 10;
    }

    for( k = 0; (j - k) > 0 && ret; k++, j-- )
    {
        if( number[j-1] != number[k] )
        {
            ret = 0;
        }
    }
    return( ret );
}

int is_huiwen_1( int L )
{
    int ret = 1;
    int y = 0;
    int t = L * L;
    int x = t;

    do
    {
        y = y * 10 + t % 10;
        t /= 10;
    }
    while( t );

    if( x != y )
    {
        ret = 0;
    }
    return( ret );

}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        flag = is_huiwen_1(i);

        if(flag)
        {
            printf("1: %d is huiwen\n",i);
        }
    }

    for( i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        flag = is_huiwen_2(i);

        if(flag)
        {
            printf("2: %d is huiwen\n",i);
        }
    }

    printf("end\n");

    return( 0 );
}
```

I don't know what all the variables do. The use of 'l' looks like a '1' in some editors.

Being a Code Refactoring monk or zealot, I did some modifications such as reducing the code to one consistent return condition, value and point of return.
While it might seem overly simple, having multiple declarations on one line hides trouble, such as `int i` not being used in the second function.
The use of `int numbers[20] = { 0 };` was also misleading us as for the range of values here `[20]` was overkill, having an explanation of what the range of values "12321", "1234321" where could have meant easier debugging of this code. A simple comment of what the outcome should look like would have solved several problems.

```
// A Huiwen number looks like this "12321", "1589851"
```

While this might be a simple exercise it portends greater problems down the line if this was not a trivial exercise. Try not to make it hard on the next coder.

Document your algorithms, arithmetic and variables please.